# Layout with scroll bar in between two containers, but fill available space

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

[image]

I'm trying to achieve a layout but it seems more complicated then it really is.

**A** does not have a fixed height.
**C** can have a fixed height.
**B** needs to be able to scroll on overflow, but not shrink A or B but fill available space.

What's the easiest way to achieve this layout? I've tried it with flex but when overflow occurs on B, it seems to shrink C no matter what even when `flex-shrink: 0` is applied to C.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with flex setting `order` to your elements.

In this example the mid container will get the avalaible space left scrolling if necesary while both top and bot containers will grow depending on content. You can add to them a fixed height if you wish (C in your example):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.top {
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.mid {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  order: 2;
  background-color: blue;
      overflow: auto;
}
.bot {  
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    asdasdas <br>
    asdasdas <br>
    asdasdas <br>
    asdasdas <br>
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
  asdasdas <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    asdasdas
  </div>
  <div class="bot">
  asdasdas <br>
    asdasdas <br>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `relative` and `z-index` ?

Comment: Ops, you can remove it. It's a layout I use on many of my projects. Will edit removing it